# (In Xcode) Unexpectedly Found Nil while Unwrapping an optional value

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm coding a space invaders type app right now, and I recently ran into a really annoying fatal error that freezes my game. I'm trying to get a laser to take the enemy off of the screen, except as soon as the player, enemy, or laser come in-tact with each other, the game then freezes. I've tried force unwrapping it and everything, but nothing seems to work. Here is the area the error is at the moment:  `if body2.node == nil{ if ((body2.node!.position.y)) > self.size.height{` The error is in the line with if((body2.node. My error states: "Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value". FYI, I'm using the solo mission tutorial by Matt Heaney apps on YouTube to code.

Comment: You are force unwrapping `body2.node` inside a condition where you already know that body2.node is nil : `if body2.node == nil`. Logic error. This crash is expected. Maybe you wanted to do the opposite? `if body2.node != nil`

Answer (score 0):

That error means, that one ore more objects of you're code wasn't initialized and may be sometimes tricky to fix. For your code please check if you initialized the object `body2` or try to provide a default value using `??`.
Best regards